# Html charset and support for special (national) characters

Tags: html, web, character-encoding

I have a website in HTML5. Most of the content there is in Czech, which has some special symbols like "ř, č, š" etc...

I searched the internet for recommended charsets and I got these answers: UTF-8, ISO 8859-2 and Windows-1250.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO 8859-2" />
```

I tried UTF-8 which didnt work at all and then settled up with ISO 8859-2. I tested my website on my computer in the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera. Everything worked fine but when I tested my website at http://browsershots.org/ , these characters were not displayed correctly (in the same browsers that I used for testing!).

How is that possible? How can I ensure, that all characters are displayed correctly in all web browsers. Is it possible that usage of HTML5 causes these problems (since its not fully supported by all browsers, but I am not using any advanced functions)?

Thanks for any hints and troubleshooting tips!

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/), [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you using HTML5, try this short declaration of charset:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Additionally check you html file encoding. You can do it in Notepad++, menu Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8.

Comment: This works for me on Microsoft Expression Web 3.0 . File > Properties > Language (tab) > HTML ENCODING - Save Document As option.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing is that the actual encoding of the data coincides with the declared encoding. From the description, it seems that the actual encoding is ISO-8859-2, so you should declare it. Note that the name of the encoding has no space but hyphens. (I wonder whether you used it with a space – I would expect browsers to ignore the tag then.) The following is the simplest declaration:

```
<meta charset=ISO-8859-2>
```

I would not trust on browsershots.org getting things like this right. Testing on actual browsers is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is the best-supported character set for international usage.  If it does not display correctly, you should ensure that your file is saved in UTF-8 format.  Even Notepad has a "UTF-8" option in its save dialog.